# Using Hoplon with the Boot Bulid Tool To Get A Clojure Backend

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, boot-clj, hoplon

This is a pretty simple problem. So far I spent all morning drying to figure out the problem. I decided to use Hoplon for my next Clojure based website and was wondering how I can start a new project with the boot build tool and Hoplon to include a backend. The code below is how to make a template without a backend on bash.

```
boot -d boot/new new -t hoplon -n address-book
```

Cheers,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean with a Castra component?

boot -d boot/new new -t hoplon-castra -n myprojectname